# Grant IAP to users that have another app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a paid application (iPhone and iPad apps are non-universal) on the AppStore that includes no IAP. I'd like to create a free universal version that gives all the features of the paid version, but through buying optional IAP.

I'd like to be able to give everyone who already bought the paid non-universal version all the IAP of the free version w/IAP for free. Meaning, I don't want people who already bought the paid version to have to re-buy features in the universal 'free' version that they already have in the paid version.

How could I check to see if people already own the paid version and then grant them the IAP for free? One way I was thinking is looking for the URL scheme of the paid version on their device and if found then somehow unlock the IAP in the free version.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is really the only solution if you want to put out a new free app.

Or you could change the currently paid app into a free app with IAP instead of putting out a new app. If you only support iOS 7 or later you can do receipt validation to see if they originally purchased the app when it was a paid app. If so, give them full access to the app without the need to pay again.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem with going from paid to free with the same app is that it's currently 2 apps (one iPhone and one iPad) and I'd like to now make it 1 universal app. Is it possible to do receipt validation on a different app by the same developer?

Comment: You didn't mention that important detail in your question. In that case your original idea is the only option. An app can only validate its own receipt.

Comment: What would be the best way to grant the IAP to these users (once I know who they are)? Since a paid IAP can't be made free from some people, I'd probably have to just manage this on a server, right? Ideally, i'd be able to tell apple to give it to them for free so I wouldn't have to manager a server, but that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Your new app looks for the old app using the old app's custom URL scheme. If found, your new app simply provides all functionality. No IAP needed.

Comment: Right, however users are then unlikely to keep the old app. So, there would need to be a way to store whether the user has all functionality once they remove the old app. If it were possible to grant all the IAP, then it could all be managed by restoring IAP, but since that doesn't seem possible, it seems this would have to be managed by storing on a server (or keychain possibly).